# difference between int* and char* in c++

Tags: c++, pointers

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int * a[5];
    char * b[5];
    cout<<a[1]; // this works and prints address being held by second element in the array  
    cout<<b[1]; // this gives run time error . why ?
    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone please explain to me `cout<<b[1]` gives run-time error ?
Shouldn't  both int and char array behave similar to each other ?

Comment: you mean if it was initialized , there woudn't be an error ?

Comment: Think about what happens if you do `const char* s = "Hello"; std::cout << s;` and then think about whether you really expect `int*` and `char*` to behave the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because IOStreams are designed to treat `char*` specially.

`char*` usually points to a C-string, so IOStreams will just assume that they do and dereference them.

Yours don't.

Answer (score 3):

As others have said, iostream formatted output operators consider `char*` to point to C-style string and attempt to access this string.

What others have not said so far, is that if you are interested in the pointer, you need to cast the pointer in question to `void*`. For example:

```
std::cout << static_cast<const void*>(buf[1]);
```

Answer (score 2):

C++ (inheriting it from C) treats character pointers specially. When you try to print `a[1]` of type `int*` the address is printed. But when you try to print `b[1]` of type `char*` the iostream library - following the rest of the language - assumes that the pointer points to the first character of zero-terminated string of characters. Both your output statements are initialised behaviour, but in the case of `char*` crash is much more likely because the pointer is dereferenced.

Comment: There is no 'rest of the language' which treats char* as c-strings unconditionally.

Comment: @SergeyA How about C library, other parts of C++ library (e.g. std::string), type of string literals?

Comment: C library makes no attempt to differentiate behavior based on argument type - for a simple reason of C lacking functions overloading altogether. As for `std::string`, it specifically expects `char*` in it's methods, and mandates it to point to nul-terminated string (unless size is also passed in constructor). As for type of string literal, I do not see how it is related at all.

Comment: @Sergey Let me explain it to you then. Most of C++ treats char* as pointer to zero-terminated sequence of characters. E.g. type of string literals, std::string constructor, type_info::name, etc. etc. Iostreams is just another example. I wonder what you meant by your "there is no rest of the language" because even in your next comment you provide examples from the rest of the language (i.e. not iostreams).

Comment: _"To print the string it dereferences the pointer, which is undefined behaviour because the pointer is not initialised."_ N.B. the `int*` case is also undefined behaviour if `a[1]` is an uninitialized value. Printing an uninitialized pointer is undefined, even if you don't dereference it.

Comment: You do not get it. Everywhere you see, specific functions expect a specific argument - they expect a C-style string. They fail when something which is not such a string is passed, and they do not work differently based on the type of argument passed. iostreams is very special in this regard - it really changes semantics based on argument type, and it is unique in this sense.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Correct.

Comment: @SergeyA I am afraid it was you not getting something. I said that iostream treats char* as zero-terminated string, and that it is not unique to iostream - many other C++ elements treat char* the same. It is true, isn't it? So e.g. std::string constructor treats char* as zero-terminated strings "unconditionally" - contrary to your first comment. I understand what you try to say about uniqueness of iostream (since other pointers may be used in the same context as char*), but it does not make your first comment true.

Comment: With that I agree. I have chosen bad words there, and I would edit it if I could.

Answer (score 2):

An output stream such as cout gives special consideration to char * that it does not give to other pointers.  For pointers other than char *, it will simply print out the value of the pointer as a hexadecimal address.  But for char *, it will try to print out the C-style (i.e. null terminated array of char) string referred to by the char *.  Therefore it will try to dereference the char pointer, as @AlexD points in the comment to your post.

Comment: iostreams do treat some other pointer types specially, `signed char` and `unsigned char` get similar treatment.